# Google Map APIv3: Disable infoWindow when using InfoBox with KML PlaceMarker

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I'm using [InfoBox for Google Map API v3](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/docs/examples.html) with a little customisation to use it with Kml PlaceMarker.

The problem is: When in my KML file I add Extended Data, a infoWindow is displayed with the infoBox. Without this Extended Data, google map doesn't display this infoWindow and it's fine, only the infoBox is displayed.

The question is: How can I force google maps to never display any infoWindow?

Comment: A link to live code would be valuable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't tell if you're talking about using `KmlLayer` because ou didn't post a link, but if you are: use the `suppressInfoWindow` option.

See the [docs](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#KmlLayer) for more information.

Comment: I don't know how I'm doing to not see this option! Thank

Comment: The option is called `suppressInfoWindows` (plural)